# C - Exception when using _int16

Tags: c, exception, stack, int, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct way to use scanf / printf (and family) with fixed size types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936798/correct-way-to-use-scanf-printf-and-family-with-fixed-size-types)

I have written the following program in Visual Studio:

Upon running the program and exiting, I get the error message "stack around variable b was corrupted".  If I replace _int 16 with int, no exception is raised.  How can I solve this problem please?  I have to use _int16 since I want to simulate an integer overflow.  Thanks :)

Comment: Your usage of `scanf` assumes a full word integer not a 16-bit integer.  Try `"%hd"` as the pattern per the [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: Thanks :)  What should I use instead please?  I am kind of new to C.

Comment: Read the scanf man page, and look for "short int".

Comment: 1) main() should return int 2) what is _int16 ( identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved) 3) if _int16 is a 16 bit type, use a "%hd" format. 4) you are using printf() and not #including <stdio.h>

Comment: Thanks wildplasser :)  That's what I needed :)

Comment: @Steve-o - you're right about the issue, but do you think, that `%hd` will be the cross-platform solution? `short int`'s size could vary, depending on the platform, right?

Comment: @KirilKirov: You're right, that is the implicit problem with (hidden) typedefs: there is no way to find the associated printf formats. Only the native `short int` is supported.

Comment: @Kiril cross platform you would use `int16_t` and `SCNd16` from `inttypes.h`

Comment: @Steve-o - interesting. I'll post a separate question about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the solution is to replace

```
scanf("%d", &a);
```

with

```
scanf("%hd", &a);
```

Comment: That will only work if `_int16` is the same size as `short`, but they need not be the same size.