# Correct way to use scanf / printf (and family) with fixed size types?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fixed-size-types

Reading [**this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936521/c-exception-when-using-int16), I started wondering - what is the correct way to use `scanf`/`printf` (and family) with fixed size types?

For example, if I have `short int` or `int`, I'd use `%hd` and `%d` respectively - fine.

But what if I have `int16_t`? `short int` may be different from `int16_t`, it's platform dependent. The same for any other fixed-size (integral) types?

---

***NOTE:*** As it looks like I received some down-votes, because I "*didn't try to google this*", it looks like I need to explain: I didn't see similar question here, that's why I posted it. Most of the questions in SO could have been answered using Google, instead of asking here. That would make StackOverflow not the place, that it actually is now.

And NO, I didn't do this for reputation - I already hit the daily reputation cap today (having 24 up votes before posting this question).

My point is - I don't think this deserves down-votes.

Comment: Don't forget to use your good friend google. ;) Gave it in a hit when searching: ["printf int16_t"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=printf+int16_t&oq=printf+int16_t&gs_l=hp.3...741.1861.0.2073.8.7.0.0.0.0.267.267.2-1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.7MPX56CVufA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ec63c9d2be74365f&bpcl=35277026&biw=1343&bih=748).

Comment: @Mike - I haven't :) I think that it'd be good to have similar question here (and no, not because of reputation - I already hit the daily reputation cap today (having 24 upvotes till now)). I don't think this deserves down votes.

Comment: +1 Agreed with your edit. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Mike - reverting down-vote appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: And this is now the #1 result on google... As are MANY other questions where people say "you should have googled it". It's a bit comical and a bit annoying seeing this conversation on half the SO questions which now happen to be the #1 google result on the subject.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct way is to use [`inttypes.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) which defines standard macros for `printf` family and the `scanf` family, e.g.

```
printf ("%" PRId16, short_int);
scanf ("%" SCNd16, &short_int);
```

Comment: Why is this better than `%d`? Wouldn't the short be converted to `int`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli包子露宪六四事件法轮功 I think printf would be aware of that conversion, and for scanf it will NOT be converted.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com `short`s  in varidiac functions would be promoted to `int`, but you aren't passing a `short` to `scanf`; you're passing a `short*`. `scanf` needs to know how many bytes to write to the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

The [inttypes.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) header file contains macros that define the correct format specifiers for fixed-width integers defined in stdint.h. For example, the type specifier for `printf()` and `int16_t` is the macro named `PRId16`. Example:

```
int16_t x;
scanf("%" SCNd16, &x);

printf("You have entered: %" PRId16 "\n", x);
```

Comment: The macros do not include the required leading `%` character.