# Hex string conversion using strtol() giving wrong output

Tags: c, strtol

I have a situation where I need to convert a hex string `0x8aaaf200` to a `uint32_t`. I first tested it on my local machine (Linux Debian box).

```
// str contains "0x8aaaf200"

uint32_t var = (uint32_t)strtol(str, NULL, 0); 
printf("conversion: %x \n\n", var); // prints 8aaaf200
```

I then ran it on a different machine (Android based), but to my surprise, the output comes out to be `7fffffff`. I think it may be related to `uint32_t` size on different machines.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix it ? I can't change the `uin32_t` type usage, as it is part of code written by someone else.

Comment: `uint32_t` is always 32 bits on any C99 compliant compiler. However the correct format specifier for it is [`PRIx32`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12936798/995714)

Comment: Try to test the value of `errno` after the conversion, it may gives some clue.

Comment: @JoëlHecht errno states `Errno: Math result not representable`

Comment: Perhaps your platform has strtoul() available, if so use it.

Comment: @TonyB: That worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually getting LONG_MAX (which is 2147483647 or 0x7FFFFFFF) as return value, which happens when the value passed to strtol is greater than LONG_MAX. You should use the unsigned type to represent that number on your machine. Please use function strtoul() in place of strtol.