# What is portable and correct way to print int_fast_32_t etc data-type

Tags: c

I have been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500677/what-is-uint-fast32-t-and-why-should-it-be-used-instead-of-the-regular-int-and-u) and have a doubt what is correct and portable way to print this datatype?

```
uint_fast8_t
uint_fast16_t
uint_fast32_t
uint_fast64_t
```

Signed as well.

Comment: You do it based on [How do I print uint32_t and uint16_t variables' value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120426/how-do-i-print-uint32-t-and-uint16-t-variables-value)

Comment: Almost duplicate, except they don't directly address `fast`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936798/correct-way-to-use-scanf-printf-and-family-with-fixed-size-types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618443/how-to-use-int16-t-or-int32-t-with-functions-like-scanf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168275/printf-format-specifiers-for-uint32-t-and-size-t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

include [`<inttypes.h>`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.8) and use the macros therein

```
#include <inttypes.h> // <inttypes.h> also includes <stdint.h> on its own
uint_fast8_t a = 0;
uint_fast16_t b = 0
uint_fast32_t c = 0;
uint_fast64_t d = 0;

printf("%" PRIuFAST8 " %" PRIuFAST16 " %" PRIuFAST32 " %" PRIuFAST64 "\n", a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: For signed counter parts is it "PRIiFAST8" etc?

Comment: Yes, I made the `<inttypes.h>` in my post clickable :)

Comment: sorry but I being blind as bat did not notice link !

Answer (score 2):

Based on @pmg answer, just for easy cut/paste / testing/reference.

```
#include <inttypes.h> // <inttypes.h> also includes <stdint.h> on its own
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

  uint_fast8_t  a = 100;
  uint_fast16_t b = 1001;
  uint_fast32_t c = 10001;
  uint_fast64_t d = 100001;

  int_fast8_t   ai = -100;
  int_fast16_t  bi = -1001;
  int_fast32_t  ci = -10001;
  int_fast64_t  di = -100001;

  uint_least8_t at = 200;
  int_least32_t ct = -200;
  

  printf ("sizeof: a:%zu b:%zu c:%zu d:%zu\n",
      sizeof (a), sizeof (b), sizeof (c), sizeof (d));
  
  printf ("sizeof: ai:%zu bi:%zu ci:%zu di:%zu\n",
      sizeof (ai), sizeof (bi), sizeof (ci), sizeof (di));
  
  printf ("sizeof (at):%zu sizeof (ct):%zu\n", sizeof (at), sizeof(ct));
  
  printf ("ufast8:%"  PRIuFAST8  " fast8:%"  PRIiFAST8  "\n", a, ai);
  printf ("ufast16:%" PRIuFAST16 " fast16:%" PRIiFAST16 "\n", b, bi);
  printf ("ufast32:%" PRIuFAST32 " fast32:%" PRIiFAST32 "\n", c, ci);
  printf ("ufast64:%" PRIuFAST32 " fast32:%" PRIiFAST64 "\n", d, di);
  
  printf ("unitleast8:%" PRIiLEAST8 " intleast32:%" PRIiLEAST32 "\n",
      at, ct);
  
}
```